# Sql Query Performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, index, query

I have one query for the report.

**Query**

```
Use RIS

select CİHAZ,sum(sayi) as [Çekim Sayısı], count(*) as [Hasta Sayısı] from
(select CİHAZ,[KABUL NO],[TC NO], count(*) as Sayi from 

(SELECT 
a.GeneralReceptionNo as [KABUL NO], pa.TRIDNO as [TC NO],
m.EtiketAdi as [CİHAZ]
FROM   Appointments a 
INNER JOIN Examinations e    ON a.ObjectID=e.AppointmentID   --aobject 1392334
INNER JOIN Patients pa       ON a.PatientID=pa.ObjectID
INNER JOIN Procedures pr     ON a.ProcedureID=pr.ObjectID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Machines m   ON a.MachineID=m.ObjectID
LEFT OUTER JOIN ExaminationReportAssistanceAssociation ra ON e.ObjectID =ra.ExaminationID  
INNER JOIN Hospital..Receptions r       ON r.GeneralReceptionNo =a.GeneralReceptionNo 
WHERE 
CONVERT (DATE,e.CompletedDate)>='2018-12-01'
AND CONVERT (DATE,e.CompletedDate)<'2019-12-30' AND e.IsCompleted =1) sorgu
GROUP BY CİHAZ,[KABUL NO],[TC NO] ) sorgu2
GROUP BY CİHAZ ORDER BY CİHAZ
```

My problem is ,when i wrote condition is `CONVERT (DATE,e.CompletedDate)>='2018-12-01'
AND CONVERT (DATE,e.CompletedDate)<'2019-11-30'` , query not ended in **50 min** but

if i wrote condition is `CONVERT (DATE,e.CompletedDate)>='2018-11-01'
AND CONVERT (DATE,e.CompletedDate)<'2019-11-30'`
 I can get the result in **12 sec**.

First example time range wider than the second example. I can't find a solution. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the type of the column e.CompletedDate ? How many rows have "IsCompleted = 1" vs 0 ?

Comment: 1. You should include Actual execution plan for both queries in your question. 2.Are you sure your first condition is correct? date >= '2018-12-01' and date < '2018-11-30' returns NOTHING

Comment: data type is smalldatetime - @DaniellePaquette-Harvey

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RIS..Examinations e
WHERE 
e.CompletedDate>='2018-12-01' 
and e.CompletedDate<'2019-11-30' and e.IsCompleted =1 ***75134-- result**

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RIS..Examinations e
WHERE 
e.CompletedDate>='2018-11-01' 
and e.CompletedDate<'2019-11-30' and e.IsCompleted =1

***142383 -- result***

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RIS..Examinations e
WHERE 
e.CompletedDate>='2018-12-01' 
and e.CompletedDate<'2019-11-30' and e.IsCompleted =0
***1480 -- result ***

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RIS..Examinations e
WHERE 
e.CompletedDate>='2018-11-01' 
and e.CompletedDate<'2019-11-30' and e.IsCompleted =0
***2623 -- result***

Comment: @sepupic is not correct . 

e.CompletedDate>='2018-11-01' and e.CompletedDate<'2019-11-30'
plan

https://ibb.co/h8zm9pR

Comment: @sepupic 
e.CompletedDate>='2018-12-01' 
and e.CompletedDate<'2019-11-30' plan is

https://ibb.co/r5Tp5fk

Comment: You can share full query plan with BrentOzar website : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: See the difference of thickness on the arrows in the query plans you shared? Clearly, there is way more rows returned when you query with "2018-11-01" instead of "2018-12-01". In fact, you return almost twice as much rows (142383 instead of 75134) so of course it's gonna take a long time.

Comment: You should definitely add an index on "CompletedDate" as the first column. It will allow SQL to do an index seek instead of a scan like in your plan. I would do something like this : CREATE INDEX IX_Examinations_CompletedDate ON Examinations(CompletedDate) include (AppointmentID, IsCompleted) That way, it should cover your query with the included columns. And of course updating the statistics

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the condition?

```
CONVERT (DATE,e.CompletedDate) >= '2018-11-01' 
AND CONVERT (DATE,e.CompletedDate) < '2018-11-30'
```

This query is not SARGable, just rewrite your query as

```
e.CompletedDate >= '2018-11-01' 
AND e.CompletedDate < '2018-11-30'
```

And ensure you have an index with CompletedData field as the first field. As far as I see the condition, it should work in the same way but much faster and will use minimal resources.

As per your comment, apart from the proposed change in your WHERE condition you need to create a new index as:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Examinations_CompletedDate ON Examinations(CompletedDate)
```

Comment: [2018-11-01 -- 2018-11-30](https://pasteboard.co/HUHgJM3.png)    ---                  
[2018-12-01--2018-11-30](https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HUHhWNP.png)--                             Convert using or not using dosent change anything. Still i try something .Thanks for help.

Comment: And i try to create index   but                                  
/*
USE [RIS]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Examinations] ([IsCompleted],[CompletedDate])
INCLUDE ([ObjectID],[AppointmentID])
GO
*/

time is too long.

Comment: I think you are accepting the index that the system proposed but not running the Index I recommended. Not sure wich one is better but please, try to run the command I posted to CREATE INDEX.

Comment: @Angel - the recommended one is better here. Otherwise there would be lookups needed. And an oddity about converting to date is that the QO understands this and handles it as if it’s sargable.

Comment: sorry for mistake . I add wrong date on query . I updated.

e.CompletedDate>='2018-12-01' 
and e.CompletedDate<'2019-11-30'   --example 1 -- Not ended in 50 min

e.CompletedDate>='2018-11-01' 
and e.CompletedDate<'2019-11-30' -- example 2 - Ended 12 sec

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like statistics to me. It knows how many rows there are in November but incorrectly thinks there are very few rows in December. I imagine if you look at the query plans you’ll see they’re quite different.

Try updating your statistics and seeing if things improve.

Also, do look for the missing index recommendations here, because indexes will be critical to performance.

Comment: Recommended index is

/*
USE [RIS]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Examinations] ([IsCompleted],[CompletedDate])
INCLUDE ([ObjectID],[AppointmentID])
GO
*/

but it does not reduce the time. Thanks for message.

Comment: But did you update the stats??